# Loop only the present image not continuosly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to add the different images with fadeIn and fadeOut Option. Right Now that Script makes continuously looping. But i want to make that stop the loop once it ends the last of the image and alert. That's it.
I am not sure how can i do this inorder to get alert for end of the loop.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var $imgs = $('#slideshow > img'), current = 0;

    var nextImage = function() {
        if (current >= $imgs.length) current = 0;
        $imgs.eq(current++).fadeIn(function() {
            $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(nextImage);
        })
    };
nextImage();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enUuY/1/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to replace:

```
if (current >= $imgs.length) current = 0;
```

with:

```
if (current >= $imgs.length) { 
    alert('end of images'); 
    return false; 
}
```

`return false;` will exit the method immediately.

final code should look like:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var $imgs = $('#slideshow > img'), current = 0;

    var nextImage = function() {
        if (current >= $imgs.length) {
            alert('End of images');
            return false;
        }
        $imgs.eq(current++).fadeIn(function() {
            $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(nextImage);
        })
    };
    nextImage();
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: If it is required to have the last image remain then place the code, Gal V provided, inside the fadeIn function before fade out.